# Slick slider dots functionality to custome design list

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have two column, in first column there is a list where I want to click and change slide in mobile frame, i.e. following is my html

```
<div class="convenience-wrapper">
                    <div class="convenience-content">
                        <h3>Convenience</h3>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li class="active">One</li>
                            <li>Two</li>
                            <li>Three</li>
                            <li>Four</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mobile-wrapper">
                        <div class="mobile-frame">
                            <img src="images/mobile-frame.png" alt="Mobile Frame" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="mobile-screens">
                            <img src="images/order-on-app.png" alt="Order on App" />
                            <img src="images/flexible-quantity.png" alt="Flexible quantity" />
                            <img src="images/buy-now-pay-later.png" alt="Buy now pay later" />
                            <img src="images/scan-qr.png" alt="Scan QR" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to click on left side list i.e. one, two, three and want to change slide/image in "mobile-screens" div.

I have searched a lot but everyone is repositioning and changing slick dots style, I want dots functionality at my own custom design list, anyone can guide me how to to that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
  $("#mySlider").slick({
    infinite: true
  })
  $("#myNavList > li").click((e) => {
    let element_index = [...e.target.parentElement.children].indexOf(e.target)
    $("#mySlider").slick("slickGoTo", element_index)
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="myNavList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="mySlider" style="max-width: 100%">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?1"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?2"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?3"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would personally not use the `element_index` method in production but this is just a quick demo code to explain what tools you can use to achieve what you asked for.